# Select multiple values from ng-repeat and pass to new view with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay, I'm in a quandary.. 
The idea: A web app, that can show a list of all the players (in my DB). You should then be able to pick 2 players on the list and press a play button. Then be passed on to a new view WITH the two selected players..

So, what i need is to be able to select to players from my ng-repeat list and then pass their information from my JSON on to the next view. 
For now, I just wanna print em' on the next view. I'll be able to figure out how to use them for the game myself once this is done.

Anybody? :(

Comment: You can do it with services, for example. Each time you select two players, you set up a new value in that service. Watch it over in another view, and jump in action when it's set up.

Comment: Can you show some more effort, some real code or a plnkr? Just discussing how it could be build (yes, services would be the right way) leads to vague discussions, which further readers might not find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to select more than one value is using the $index associated with the every element. Push all the selected value into the array, and check for the index of the value in the array.

**In Your view:**
ng-class="{sel: selected.indexOf($index) >= 0 }"

**In your controller**

```
$scope.select= function(index) {
   $scope.selected.push(index); 
};
```

working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/chella89/3G7Kd/173/